# Variance/Standard Deviation with a Constant Vaule

Tags: probability-or-statistics

When applying variance (`Variance[10]`) or standard deviation (`StandardDeviation[10]`) to a constant value in Mathematica, Should the return be zero ?

What I get from `StandardDeviation[10]` is the error saying that `standardDeviation::rectt: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in StandardDeviation[10]`.

How do I fix it ?

Comment: For one thing, `Variance` expects a list, so you'd need to do `Variance[{10}]` instead. But for another thing, `Variance` returns the *sample* variance, with $n-1$ in the denominator, so the variance of a sample of length $n=1$ is not defined at all.

Comment: @RahulNarain I guess the way to fix it is to replicate 10 so that I will have a list of `{10,10}`. Then, applying `Variance[{10,10}]` returns me 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, a list of one single item has no *sample variance* but it does have a *population variance*. The population variance has to be defined, though :

```
PopulationVariance[list_] := Mean[(list - Mean[list])^2];
PopulationVariance[{10}] (* 0 *)
```